# Android Navigation Url Deep Link Back to Previous App

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-deep-link

My app has just two destinations, **FirstFragment** and **SecondFragment**. I created an url Deep Link for the **SecondFragment** and it works fine.

What I want is, after I enter the **SecondFragment** from the Deep Link, I want to go back to the previous app when I press the Back button. But now it always go back to the **FirstFragment**.

I have set my **MainActivity** to `singleTask` on `launchMode` and tried the following but doesn't work:

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)

    intent!!.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

    navController.handleDeepLink(intent)

    Log.v("MainActivity", "onNewIntent() get called!")
}
```

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Comment: @Mark Still no, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The DeepLink knows about your NavGraph. And if your SecondFragment is a decendent of the FirstFragment, this is the intended behavior.

When you show your NavGraph and how you create the DeepLink it might be possible to suggest a different option.